# can't scrape ahref from airbnb site

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

hi there i am trying to scrape the url link from the a href tag but i am getting this error

```
  Input In [162] in <cell line: 1>
link = post.find('a', class_ = 'ln2bl2p dir dir-lt').get('href')   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

here is my code below. Link 24 is returning an error

[image]

website link < [https://www.airbnb.co.uk/s/Honolulu--HI--United-States/homes?tab_id=home_tab&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&flexible_trip_lengths%5B%5D=one_week&date_picker_type=calendar&place_id=ChIJTUbDjDsYAHwRbJen81_1KEs&checkin=2022-08-08&checkout=2022-08-14&source=structured_search_input_header&search_type=autocomplete_click&federated_search_session_id=82d7df97-e5c9-48d5-9dfe-ca1006489343&pagination_search=true>](https://www.airbnb.co.uk/s/Honolulu--HI--United-States/homes?tab_id=home_tab&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&flexible_trip_lengths%5B%5D=one_week&date_picker_type=calendar&place_id=ChIJTUbDjDsYAHwRbJen81_1KEs&checkin=2022-08-08&checkout=2022-08-14&source=structured_search_input_header&search_type=autocomplete_click&federated_search_session_id=82d7df97-e5c9-48d5-9dfe-ca1006489343&pagination_search=true%3E)

Comment: it might be possible that you need to use some kind of headless browser instead of making just a raw requests as airbnb page might be SPA which should be properly broswer-rendered before parsing

Comment: how do i check ?

Answer (score 0):

Are sure that you can get content with this request? Add html code which you got from request to your answer, so we would understand it. Look like you need use another request to get this data.

If you will save html code **which you got from request** here (don't use screenshots of code anymore):

```
page = requests.get(url)
with open('test.html', 'w') as f:
   f.write(page.text)
```

I am *preety sure* that you will discover that **no needed information there**.

And after that i'm trying to understand how i get this info when i'm using my own browser...

- Going to website
- Open `dev tools` (F12 in chrome)
- open `network`

If you filter packages with `Doc`, you will see html pages that server sent to you. **And there is empty page, so you are getting empty page with this request**
[image]

To find information that you need, you must find it in packages which server sent to you. Usually it's `JS` or `FETCH/XHR`.

Comment: ok please see below

Comment: @CodeNinja you don't show url on screenshot

Comment: @CodeNinja see... It's not your html... Not what you got from request

Comment: i don't understand why it doesn't return the ahref html? –

Comment: <a href=""class="ln2bl2p dir dir-ltr"/>. IS INSIDE <div class c4mnd7m dir dir-ltr/>

Comment: @CodeNinja read updates

Comment: i can't add the html code because its too big

Comment: i follow your instructions and i can see empty page when i filter doc

Comment: @CodeNinja so now follow my last point in the instruction "To find information that you need, you must find it in packages which server sent to you. Usually it's JS or FETCH/XHR." And then do same requests in your code. I will not do all your job

Comment: do you only do that if you are looking for a hidden api ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247129/discussion-between-555russich-and-code-ninja).